# Drupal 7 php loops and rendering images dynamically

Tags: php, drupal-7

I currently have a custom content type of type my article in which i have a slider attached using node-tpl.php the slider is working fine my problem is that i have image fields in this content type and i want them to be rendered in the

so that they are displayed inside the slider i cant seem to add the php snippet to the

elements am currently using this code 
print render($content['field_images'][i]); 
where i is the index in the field images array to be rendered

Full php snippet`

```
<?php
$i=0;
 $array=$html->find('li');
?>
 <?php
 foreach ($array as $value){
 print render($content['field_images'][i]);
 $i=i+1;}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can get you started.

```
foreach($content['field_images']['#items'] as $key => $value) {
    print render($content['field_images'][$key]);
}
```